# Proving existence of sinkless orientation on graph with minimum degree 2

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, matching, bipartite-matching

I am given a graph of minimum degree at least 2 (not necessairly regular). I want to prove that there is a way to orient the edges of G such that each node of G has at least one out-going edge.

As a hint I have that, in a bipartite graph $(U \biguplus V, E)$ if for every $U' \subseteq U,  |N(U')| \geq |U'|$, then there is a matching of size $|U|$.

I tried thinking subsets of nodes and edges inbetween them to form bipartite graphs, but that would take exponential effort to check for all. My idea was to take all subsets of nodes and edges in between them which satisfy the hint and apply the hint there. I tried as follows:

Let $G=(V,E)$, be general graph. I will be applying the hint on new components $(L_i ⨄ R_i, E_i)$ (only if applicable). I first find arbitrary $(L_0 ⨄ R_0, E_0)$ and apply the hint to get matching of size $|L_0|$. Then, my $R_0$ will become my $L_1$, and I am looking for corresponding $R_1$ (with nodes which are not in $L_0$) to apply the hint. I will be repeating this procedure until I pick each node is some $L_i/R_i$.

My claim is that I can achieve sinkless orientation with this algorithm which obviously will terminate. But I cannot prove that it will not have terminated before taking all nodes, i.e. after some iteration, I can no longer apply the hint.

Comment: You have to prove the *existence* of a sinkless orientation. You don't have to give an efficient algorithm for finding one (though the proof does give such an algorithm). Hence I don't understand your claim that it "would take exponential effort to check for all".

Comment: Fair point, I realize that now. Then, I would say, that for every subset of nodes and edges between those nodes, where the condition of the hint is satisfied, I can apply the hint. But again, I am reaching a dead hole. I will reformulate the question.

Comment: For the right bipartite graph, the condition will always hold, and will result in a sinkless orientation.

Comment: @Yuval Bipartite is clear, I edited the post to my initial attempt, which I am still struggling to finish.

Comment: Your attempt is unclear, since you don't explain what bipartite graphs you use. I suggest spending a few more hours on it.